# WPF RichTextBox with WingDings font selected displays weird characters

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox, rtf, wingdings

So, this piqued my intreset.  I'm making a program that uses a RichTextBox in WPF and lets users pick their font.  When the font WingDings is selected, these boxes are shown on newlines:

[image: Everything below the first line was not typed.]

The first line is "this is a test" in WingDigs, then when I hit enter, I get these boxes on the newlines.  These boxes disappear when I start typing, and they don't appear when any other fonts are selected.  When just the boxes are shown, the caret position is between the two boxes and I can't select them with my mouse.  Has anyone seen this?  I don't have a TextChanged event in the background.

Here is the RTF code behind this picture, as you can see, the new lines don't have any text in them to produce these boxes.

```
{\rtf1\ansi\ansicpg1252\uc1\htmautsp\deff2{\fonttbl{\f0\fcharset0 Times New Roman;}{\f2\fcharset0 Tahoma;}{\f3\fcharset2 Wingdings;}}{\colortbl\red0\green0\blue0;\red255\green255\blue255;}\loch\hich\dbch\pard\plain\ltrpar\itap0{\lang1033\fs16\f2\cf0 \cf0\ql{\f3 {\ltrch this is a test}\li0\ri0\sa0\sb0\fi0\ql\par}
{\f3 {\ltrch }\li0\ri0\sa0\sb0\fi0\ql\par}
{\f3 {\ltrch }\li0\ri0\sa0\sb0\fi0\ql\par}
{\f3 {\ltrch }\li0\ri0\sa0\sb0\fi0\ql\par}
{\f3 {\ltrch }\li0\ri0\sa0\sb0\fi0\ql\par}
{\f3 {\ltrch }\li0\ri0\sa0\sb0\fi0\ql\par}
{\f3 {\ltrch }\li0\ri0\sa0\sb0\fi0\ql\par}
{\f3 {\ltrch }\li0\ri0\sa0\sb0\fi0\ql\par}
```

Any yes, I know the easy solution is to not list WingDings :)